# Can I replace domain.com/images/ to something like @/images/?

Tags: html

Hi I'm making a basic HTML website using Microsoft WebMatrix locally. When I've finished the website I will be uploading it to my web hosting.

Right now I'm using http://localhost:80/ to view my site and I'm using this sort of code...

```
<!--#include virtual="include/html/menu.html" -->
```

... to include the menu links so that I only have to change 1 file to change the menu across the whole site.

Here's the problem. The menu links have to have the full address like...

```
<a href="http://domain.com/service/index.html">Service</a>
```

to make sure they work on every page. Not...

```
<a href="../service/index.html">Service</a>
```

I could put http://localhost:80/service/index.html as the full address link and it would work. But, when it comes to uploading the site to domain.com the links would be broken and I'd have to change them everytime I upload a newer version of the site.

Is there anything like this...

```
<a href="@/service/index.html">Service</a>
```

... where a sign, for example @, would be whatever domain the site is on?

Comment: `<a href="<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/service.html">Service</a>`

Comment: If you can use php, I don't know anything about WebMatrix... (Can't edit comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While starting with `http://etc` is an absolute path, and starting with `../` is relative to the document in question, starting with `/` will be relative to the root of your site.

So your example would simply be `<a href="/service.html">Service</a>`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for explaining in thorough too.

Comment: This won't work if your app is not installed on the root of the domain, but in a subfolder. If your app runs from `http://www.thesite.com/` it will work. But if you need to install your app in `http://www.thesite.com/appFolder/` it will fail.